# How to create GSON custom serializer that writes raw string?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a payload class that already has the capability of writing itself to a string in JSON format. Now I would like to return a JSON object containing an array of my payload classes. I am using GSON and would like to create a custom type adapter that would simply call payload.getAsJson() and write that raw string to JsonWriter.
Unfortunately this is not working for me, as the string gets escaped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

An adapter could look like the sample below:

```
public class MyTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyPayload> {

  // Just added this as a sample assuming you have a constructor that 
  // builds a Payload instance from a String
  public MyPayload read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
      reader.nextNull();
      return null;
    }

    String json = reader.nextString();
    return new MyPayload(json);
  }

  // use value.getAsJson() for conversion
  public void write(JsonWriter writer, MyPayload value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      writer.nullValue();
      return;
    }

    String json = value.getAsJson();
    writer.value(json);
  }
}
```

It converts a Json String to a Payload instance and vice versa, assuming you have an appropriate constructor. If you don't need it, just return `null` in the method body.

This is how you use it:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(MyPayload.class, new MyTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = builder.create();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(somethingThatContainsMyPayloads);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am afraid the writer.value(String) method will actually escape the string...

Comment: Well, I made a test with `return "AB\\..{_}[]\"C";` in `getAsJson()` and this is the String being generated: `"AB\\..{_}[]\"C"`; so no escaping. I'm afraid it's even no longer useful, though in fact very unescaped :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of `Gson` @Trinimon was using, but as @FilipFrącz pointed out, the String is still being escaped.

Fortunately, it's a minor fix; in the `MyTypeAdapter` simply replace `out.value(value.getAsJson());` with `out.jsonValue(value.getAsJson());`.

**Version:** [`com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.6.2%7Cjar)

**e.g.**

#### JsonRawTypeAdapter.java

```java
public class JsonRawTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<JsonRaw> {

    @Override
    public JsonRaw read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }
        return new JsonRaw(in.nextString());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, JsonRaw value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }
        out.jsonValue(value.getAsJson());
    }

}
```

---

#### WebMvcConfig.java (snippet)

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(JsonRaw.class, new JsonRawTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

Comment: @FilipFrącz - just use `out.jsonValue(value.getAsJson());`